# Sorry you dont have access to this page

Tags: migration, security, access, sharepoint-on-prem

I am currently experiencing a very unusual issue with a SharePoint 2013 on-premise. We have done performed a migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 and when logged in as a user who is not a site collection administrator they are seeing the message "Sorry you don't have access to this page".

We are currently finding however if you click black in the browser and navigate to the same page again then the users can access the page fine.

We have give all users read permissions to the master page gallery and everything is checked in, published and approved.

I have seen a few posts about user accounts not using claims authentication and we have run a script convert the user accounts however we are still seeing the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have u set the portal super reader and super user accounts with the new claims format...??? You can refer this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ff758656.aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the user policy for the web application which occurs the issue in the Central Administration –>”Manage Web Applications”->”User Policy” and make sure the account has “full control” access.
2. Check the permission policy for the web application which occurs the issue in the Central Administration –>”Manage Web Applications”->”Permission Policy”->”Full Control” and make sure it has grant the “Apply Themes and Boards” access.
3. You can recreate a site collection to test whether it works properly.

Try the following also:

SharePoint 2010 / 2013: Access Denied to claims web apps

Feel free to reply if there are still any questions.

Comment: Hi Gowtham, so does that mean I need to add to give every user who is having the access full control access via the User Policy?